# Change step with save height Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, height

I have a simple line chart on Highcharts:

[image]

I need to change height to 250px, but when I change height of chart - step (50) on Y axes has changed too (100):

[image]

How I can change height without change step?

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        alignTicks: true,
        type: 'line',
        reflow: false,
        height: 250 //how i can do it in this case?
    },

  labels: { 
    style: { 
      left: '100px',
      top: '50px'
    }},
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: [2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016],
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        title: {
            text: null
        }
    },

    yAxis: {
        minTickInterval: 50,
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        min: 0,
        max: 350,
        startOnTick: false,
        showFirstLabel: false,
        title: {
            text: null
        }
    },

    exporting: { 
        enabled: false,
        printButton: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [313.75, 323.75, 313.75, 323.75,313.75],
        showInLegend: false
    }]

});
});
```

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Why you are using `minTickInterval`? I think there should be `tickInterval`.

Comment: Are you happen to know how to display all years, even if not enough information in "series" option? For example - I have five years (2012,2013,2014,2015,2016), but series is two (313.75, 323.75), and when I display graphic - it displays only first two years (2012 and 2013) in X axes.

Comment: Set `max: number_of_categories-1` (in your example: `max: 4`).